# Don't understand proof that union of open sets is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

All of the proofs I read of this are pretty much the same, but they all don't explain the last part of the proof and end it there because I assume they think it is obvious to everyone.

The proofs usually go like: Let $S = \bigcup_{i \in I} S_i$ for open sets $S_i$. Prove that $S$ is open. If $x$ is in some $S_i$, since $S_i$ is open, $\forall x \in S_i$ $\exists r > 0$ such that $N_r(x) \subset S_i \subset \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} S_i = S$. Thus $S$ is open.

I don't understand the final implication. We want to show that in $S$, every element of all sets are possible to be the center of an open ball around them with some radius that is contained within $S$. We've only stated that some $S_i$ is an open subset of $S$, which is actually a given so we haven't proven anything. Can someone explain the final part?

Comment: Yes but $S_i$ is contained in $S$ so the open ball is also in $S$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the open ball $N_r(x)$ is not only a subset of some $S_i$, it is also a subset of $S$. The transitive property of the subset relation is being used.

Comment: I understand that the open ball $N_r(x)$ is also a subset of the larger $S$. But I fail to see why this makes $S$ open, because in order for $S$ to be open, every element of $S$ needs to be the center of an open ball contained in $S$, and so far all we've done is only shown that there exists one ball in $S$ so far (the $N_r(x)$ one).

Comment: @user130018: What do you want more? The existence of an open ball around every $x$ that is contained in $S$ is _exactly_ the defintion of $S$ being open. You're even quoting that definition yourself in the same breath. You seem to be saying "we need to prove such-and-such but so far all we've done is to prove such-and-such".

Comment: Is your issue that we only seem to have found a ball in $S$ for only one point?

Comment: @user130018 I think your confusion stems  from not recognizing that we started by picking an *arbitrary* $x\in S$ and proceed to show that $N_r(x)\subseteq S$. This means that *every* $x\in S$ satisfies $N_r(x)\subseteq S$, and it is this that implies that $S$ is open - i.e. we have discharged the $x$ in the last line of the proof.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Ah, thank you, that was it

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Well, we're not really "picking" $x$ -- the adversary picks one for us, and we're just reacting to _his_ pick.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, perhaps a poor word choice there.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Interesting way of view an arbitrary object.  I've never heard it described that way.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski: It's more or less the Brouwer-Heyting-Kolmogorov interpretation of $\forall$. A game metaphor where various things are picked either by us or an adversary seems to be widely used in freshman analysis courses for making the meaning of, say, $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definitions more concrete. (Or at least was when (and where) I was an undergraduate).